# CONCAT and INNER JOIN - Using lookup table for one-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below creates a hierarchical relationship with tables and records:

```
program -> accreditation_standard_group -> accreditation_standard -> learning_event
```

Based on the following tables structures:

```
Table program:
        +------------+----------------+
        | program_pk |  program_name  |         
        +------------+----------------+
        
Table accreditation_standard_group: 
        +---------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+
        | accreditation_standard_group_pk |  accreditation_standard_group | program_fk |            
        +---------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+
        
Table accreditation_standard:     

        +---------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------+
        | accreditation_standard_pk | accreditation_standard | accreditation_standard_group_fk |          
        +---------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------+
    
Table learning_event:     
        +-------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+
        | learning_event_pk |  learning_event_name | accreditation_standard_fk |            
        +-------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+
```

I now need to change this so that instead of using a reference to `accreditation_standard_fk` in table `learning_event`, it uses a lookup table for One to Many relationships.

So the lookup table `learning_event_accreditation_standard_lookup` is:

```
    +-------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
    | learning_event_accreditation_standard_lookup_pk | learning_event_fk | accreditation_standard_fk |          
    +-------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------+



   SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
           program_name AS name,
           NULL AS parent_global_id
    FROM program
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_pk) AS global_id,
           accreditation_standard_group AS name,
           CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM accreditation_standard_group 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard) AS global_id,
           accreditation_standard AS name,
           CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM accreditation_standard
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
           learning_event_name AS name,
           CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard) AS parent_global_id
    FROM learning_event le
    INNER JOIN accreditation_standard ass ON ass.accreditation_standard_pk = le.accreditation_standard_fk
    INNER JOIN accreditation_standard_group asg ON ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk = asg.accreditation_standard_group_pk
```

I have tried the following but not working

> 'Column 'learning_event_name' in field list is ambiguous'

```
 SELECT 
           CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
           learning_event_name AS name,
           CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', accreditation_standard) AS parent_global_id
    FROM learning_event le
    INNER JOIN accreditation_standard ass ON ass.accreditation_standard_pk = learning_event_accreditation_standard_lookup.accreditation_standard_fk
    INNER JOIN learning_event le2 ON le2.learning_event_pk = learning_event_accreditation_standard_lookup.learning_event_fk
    INNER JOIN accreditation_standard_group asg ON ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk = asg.accreditation_standard_group_pk
```

See [**db-fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6PiURUaDwpdaXHmHCiJjsB/2)

A working fiddle work be good...

Comment: That's just saying you have more than one column present in those tables you joined with `learning_event_name` as column name. See [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6PiURUaDwpdaXHmHCiJjsB/2). Now it's telling a different error message saying that `ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'learning_event_accreditation_standard_lookup.accreditation_standard_fk' in 'on clause'`

Comment: That column exists in the fiddle.  See new fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d99vETvC2asxA7i9K7K4R3/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL runs - you had issues with the ordering of your inner joins:

```
   SELECT CONCAT('program:', p.program_pk) AS global_id,
           p.program_name AS name,
           NULL AS parent_global_id
    FROM program p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', asg.accreditation_standard_group_pk) AS global_id,
           asg.accreditation_standard_group AS name,
           CONCAT('program:', asg.program_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM accreditation_standard_group asg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', acs.accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', acs.accreditation_standard) AS global_id,
           acs.accreditation_standard AS name,
           CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', acs.accreditation_standard_group_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM accreditation_standard acs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', ass.accreditation_standard, ',learning_event:', le.learning_event_name) AS global_id,
           le.learning_event_name AS name,
           CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', ass.accreditation_standard) AS parent_global_id
    FROM learning_event le
    INNER JOIN learning_event_accreditation_standard_lookup lup ON le.learning_event_pk = lup.learning_event_fk
    INNER JOIN accreditation_standard ass ON ass.accreditation_standard_pk = lup.accreditation_standard_fk
    INNER JOIN accreditation_standard_group asg2 ON ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk = asg2.accreditation_standard_group_pk
```

Answer (score 2):

Qualify *all* column references.  Get used to doing this whenever you write queries, and you won't have problems like this.

Table aliases are your friend here.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', p.program_pk) AS global_id,
       p.program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id
FROM program p
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', asg.accreditation_standard_group_pk) AS global_id,
       asg.accreditation_standard_group AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', asg.program_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM accreditation_standard_group asg
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', acs.accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', acs.accreditation_standard) AS global_id,
       acs.accreditation_standard AS name,
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', acs.accreditation_standard_group_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM accreditation_standard acs
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', ass.accreditation_standard, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       le.learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('accreditation_standard_group:', ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk, ',accreditation_standard:', ass.accreditation_standard) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le JOIN
     accreditation_standard ass
     ON ass.accreditation_standard_pk = le.accreditation_standard_fk JOIN
     accreditation_standard_group asg
     ON ass.accreditation_standard_group_fk = asg.accreditation_standard_group_pk;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on the query logic itself. Mysql doesn't know how to handle it and it is raising an error

The message is telling you that you need to determine from what table to take the `learning_event_name` value since it is in more than one table. Just prepend the table name like `<tablename>.learning_event_name` and the query will return its values.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem though.  Could you provide a working solution for using the lookup table?